# Using an enum to specialise a template

Tags: c++, templates

I have been using a template with an enum argument to provide specialised methods for output from my code.

```
template <Device::devEnum d>
struct sensorOutput;

template<>
struct sensorOutput <Device::DEVICE1>
{
    void setData(Objects& objs)
    {
        // output specific to DEVICE1
        // output velocity
        objs.set(VELOCITY, vel[Device::DEVICE1]);
        // output position
        objs.set(POSITION, pos[Device::DEVICE1]);
    }
};

template <>
struct sensorOutput <Device::DEVICE2>
{

    void setData()
    {
        // output specific to DEVICE2
        // output altitude
        objs.set(ALTITUDE, alt[Device::DEVICE2]);
    }
};
```

I now want add another sensor similar to DEVICE1 that will output velocity and position.

Is there a way of setting multiple specialisations? I have tried

```
template <>
struct sensorOutput <Device::DEVICE1 d>
struct sensorOutput <Device::DEVICE3 d>
{

    void setData()
    {
        // output specific to DEVICE1 and DEVICE3
        // output velocity
        objs.set(VELOCITY, vel[d]);
        // output position
        objs.set(POSITION, pos[d]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about inheritance?

```
template<Device::devEnum d>
struct sensorOutputVeloricyAndPosition
{
    void setData()
    {
        // output specific to DEVICE1 and DEVICE3
        // output velocity
        objs.set(VELOCITY, vel[d]);
        // output position
        objs.set(POSITION, pos[d]);
    }
}


template<>
struct sensorOutput<Device::DEVICE1> : public sensorOutputVeloricyAndPosition<Device::DEVICE1>
{ };

template<>
struct sensorOutput<Device::DEVICE3> : public sensorOutputVeloricyAndPosition<Device::DEVICE3>
{ };
```